# How to check covariate is balanced?

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, predictor

[image]

I try to check if the covariate is balanced by computing the absolute pooled standardized difference, but I don't know how I could get the sample variance for my treated and control covariate? any suggestion could be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: If you think about marital status as a binomial random variable, you can use the binomial variance $np(1-p)$ to get a variance estimate for each group, where $p$ is the probability of being married.